# ¿Como hacer un login en C# con contraseña encriptada en MD5 de MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, login, md5

Quiero aprender a desencriptar la contraseña encriptada en MySQL por el método MD5 de un login hecho en C# para dar acceso a un programa hecho en el mismo lenguaje.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Teóricamente no puedes. MD5 es un algoritmo de cifrado irreversible. Pero tiene la ventaja que una misma entrada (clave), siempre produce la misma salida (cadena encriptada)

Entonces, la forma de validar la contraseña seria que cuando el usuario ingresa nuevamente la contraseña, volver a encriptarla con MD5 y compararla con la version ya encriptada que tienes en la base de datos. Si ambas firmas MD5 coinciden entre si, entonces el usuario ha ingresado la contraseña correcta.

Notas: MD5 se considera un algoritmo de cifrado vulnerable para ciertas aplicaciones pero no para contraseñas. Sin embargo sigue siendo un algoritmo bastante malo para cifrar contraseñas porque **es muy rapido**, osea que tiene bajo costo computacional y es relativamente barato hallar una contraseña por fuerza bruta. Para mejorar la seguridad es recomendable que utilices un algoritmo mas lento como bcrypt.

Salu2